# Interpretation of the testing data of my vehicle

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering

This is a plot of Yaw moment vs Lateral acceleration of my vehicle. I know that it can give me the analysis of trimmed conditions during cornering, yet unable to properly quantify it. What all can I achieve out of this plot. Thanks[image]

Comment: Perhaps start by selecting only left turns at a specific speed to reduce the amount of data - then you may be able to take an average for example.

Comment: @SolarMike Can't we comment anything for the present plot. Like what's the significance of the V shaped plot. why it's higher towards the left side ? Meaning of yaw moment at max acceleration regions( rightmost and leftmost point ).

Comment: Perhaps the meaning of the left and right extreme points is evidence of handbrake turns...

Comment: could you disclose at least parts of your data? Its really hard to know what information you have other that a lot of data-points.

Comment: This data is for a practice skid pad track of 8.55 mm radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to find in the data?
Under normal circumstances, ie. no drifing or such the following can be assumed; at the same vehicle speed, lateral acceleration is inherent to yaw speed, and the yaw speed is inherent to the corner radius. So yaw acceleration, or yaw moment as you can also define it, is created when steering into a corner. Theoretically, it is 0 the moment you keep the steering wheel at any steady position.

The above is theoretic, and based on formulas and basis physics. In automotive world, the highly dynamic reality ofter differs vastly from the theory we've learned. Explaining the V shape would be very hard to explain with only formulas and theoretic blahblah. The below is what my intuition tells me happens in reality:

You don't suddely steer, and keep the steering wheel in position like a step response, but you gradually steer in, creating yaw moment during steering since the corner radius decreases. Yaw moment is higher in slow sharp corners, since you turn the steering wheel fast. Those sharp corners are made at a *relatively* high speed, making for high lateral acceleration, explaining the upper right and left corners of your V. At the highway, you would steer relatively gently and slower, since situations are more dangerous at higher speeds, and your tyres aren't able to pull the same stunts at higher speeds without breaking out.
This explains why the upper corners meet in a mutual point, creating a V shape.

The fact that the upper left corner is higher likely indicates that your turns in one direction(probably right turns) are made faster than the other direction. Probably caused by the fact that you can oversee corners better, and that you have the right of way, and have to slow down less.

Comment: This data is for a practice skid pad track of 8.55 mm radius.

Comment: @AnshumanSinha So you what is the point of analysing this data? Do you want to get parameters to use for testing on your skid pad? Do you want to test tyres?